# Android make call activity to check prepaid phone balance

Tags: android

I would like to make an activity where i can call a certain numer to check my prepaid phone balance. 
In my provider its for example *555# then i will get a response like for example "Your remaining phone credit is 5 USD". I would like to use this data (5 USD) to save in the database.

I am just a beginner, does someone know how to proceed?

Comment: what you're trying to achieve is a bit more difficult than you're thinking it is. however, if this is something you can check online there's probably a way to do this with an HTTP client

Comment: I don't think its really viable. At least not in a simple way. Since what you're doing, even if you call it with an intent from you app, doesn't return any "result" as far as I know

Comment: Calling seems to be the easiest part , but how to really handle the USSD response ? I don't think that there is an API for ussd yet .check this : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1285

Comment: Nmd. I get it. These aren't your users. But I'm still confused as to why you need to save user's data in a DB? If I'm using your app to see how much I have on my account, I certainly don't expect you to save this data for whatever you plan to use it for...

Answer (score 3):

<strike>You could issue a `CALL` intent (which requires a permission) and use a broadcast receiver to listen for the SMS response (again, permission required).</strike>

However, this isn't a very robust solution as you have to check the SMS sender id and the message text, whcih may change in the future.

**EDIT**

As pointed out in comments, you will need to use the USSD protocol for this. It definitely appears possible, as there is an app that does just that: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iba.ussdchecker&hl=en.

These threads may be helpful:

- [Call (and get the response for) a USSD Code, in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193343/call-and-get-the-response-for-a-ussd-code-in-the-background)
- [How to run USSD commands on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225100/how-to-run-ussd-commands-on-android)
- [How is it possible to do USSD requests on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477597/how-is-it-possible-to-do-ussd-requests-on-android)

Comment: it's not an SMS response , it's a USSD request with a USSD answer .

Comment: @TonythePony any idea how to track mobile prepaid balance using USSD