# Can USSD response message be read/parsed through Awareness API on Android?

Tags: android, google-api, ussd

Is there any trick to read and parse USSD response message by implementing Awareness API? I am searching a way read and parse USSD response. But according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28083067/how-to-read-intercept-ussd-message-comming-on-android-phone) there is no way to do this after **Android 4.2.2** version.

In **Google I/O 2016** Awareness API is introduced. Going through the API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/awareness/overview) , I found no easy way to read USSD response message. But is there any hack to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to do this using the API you mentioned. As Awareness API does not have enough documentation to read/parse USSD message, you have to wait until a new announcement from Google.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I have to wait in this situation. Hope Google will think about the developers and will solve the issue.