# Having problem to Run USSD code in android application

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop an Android application that can perform some task using USSD code.

**Example task 1:**

I need to check mobile banking balance. To do that I need to run USSD code by following.

```
>> *245# system will display 
        1 send money
        2 balance 
        Text BOX
```

If I give 1 to the text box it will  send another text box to enter my pin. If my pin is right it will show my balance.

How can I implement those to an application, or how can I do that in one request?

Suppose it can be `*245*2*mypin#`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make USSD call in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317981/make-ussd-call-in-android)

Comment: Check this answer it will be helpful for you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4235614/5261601

Comment: yeah bro. this problem to me. thanks I can try following that.